# Getting an error creating a button after a function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

Why am I getting an error when trying to create a button after a function.

The variable `button1` is in red after the last line of the function `importFile()`.

Is the function incomplete?

this is my code

```
import glob
import os.path
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 250)
canvas1.pack()

label0 = tk.Label(root, text='Import Latest File')
label0.config(font=('helvetica', 15))
canvas1.create_window(250, 45, window=label0)

entry1 = tk.Entry (root, width = 40) 
canvas1.create_window(350, 100, window=entry1)

entry2 = tk.Entry (root, width = 40) 
canvas1.create_window(350, 140, window=entry2)

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Enter Directory Path:')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(150, 100, window=label1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Enter File Type:')
label2.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(165, 140, window=label2)

def importFile ():  
   folder_path = entry1.get()
   file_type = entry2.get()
   file_type = '\*' + file_type

   files = glob.glob(folder_path + file_type)
   max_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)

   import_file = pd.read_csv(max_file)
   #print (import_file)

button1 = tk.Button(text='Import File', command=importFile, bg='brown', fg='white', font= 
 ('helvetica', 10, 'bold'), width = 20)
 canvas1.create_window(250, 200, window=button1)

 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct indentation? The code that you posted doesn't have the correct indentation. Also why is there a white space before the `button1 = ...` line?

Comment: Hello! I edited the code here with what I think is the correct indentation and removed the white space, but I could be wrong as I'm new at python. I still have the same problem.

Comment: After removing the white spaces before the `canvas1.create_window(250, 200, window=button1)` and the `root.mainloop()`, your program ran fine. Is there an error that you're getting? If so, please show us the full error traceback.

Comment: You are correct. The little things! Thank you